# Filter subform based on combobox in main form

Tags: vba, combobox

I'v got this code:

```
Private Sub Kombinationsboks3_Change()
   Me.Tilmeldt_underformular1.Form.FilterOn = False
   Me.Tilmeldt_underformular1.Form.Filter = "[Afdeling]= 'Ansøgningsafdelingen'"
   Me.Tilmeldt_underformular1.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

In stead of the field [Afdeling] being equal to a specific text, I need it to be equal to the value in the combobox on the main form Form_Afdelinger.

I've tried searching around, but I can't seem to find the answer, so I'm hoping one of you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to complete this with the value by concatenating it to the string like so:

```
Private Sub Kombinationsboks3_Change()
   Me.Tilmeldt_underformular1.Form.FilterOn = False
   Me.Tilmeldt_underformular1.Form.Filter = "[Afdeling]= '" & [Form].[ComboBox1].Value & "'"
   Me.Tilmeldt_underformular1.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Note: You'll need to change `Form` to the parent forms name and `ComboBox1` to the ComboBox's name.